# Different delegates for QML ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I would like to know if it's possible to use (several) different delegates for a QML `ListView`.

Depending on the individual object in the `ListView` model, I would like to visualize the objects with different delegates.

This piece of code explains what I want to achieve:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ListModel {
        id: contactsModel
        ListElement {
            name: "Bill Smith"
            position: "Engineer"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "John Brown"
            position: "Engineer"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Sam Wise"
            position: "Manager"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: contactsView
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        orientation: Qt.Vertical
        spacing: 10
        model: contactsModel
        delegate: {
            if (position == "Engineer") return Employee;  //<--- depending on condition, load Contact{}
            else if (position == "Manager") return Manager; //<--- depending on condition, load Person{}
        }
    }
}
```

**Employee.qml** (One possible Component which I would like to use as a delegate)

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle{
    width: 200
    height: 50
    color: ListView.isCurrentItem ? "#003366" : "#585858"
    border.color: "gray"
    border.width: 1

    Text{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "white"
        text: name
    }
}
```

**Manager.qml** (other Component I would like to use as a delegate)

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle{
    width: 200
    height: 50
    color: "red"
    border.color: "blue"
    border.width: 1

    Text{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "white"
        text: name
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any advice!
Thanks!

Comment: In this case you can also consider the creation of a unique `delegate` which uses `position` in bindings to change its aspect. Otherwise you can use a `Loader` but you have to forward some information to the inner `item`, i.e. the real delegates. Also Folibis solution can work, but I don't think it would in this case since `position` is itself a role.

Comment: Why don't you simply define a `delegate` containing both the `Rectangle`s and set their `visible` field on a per `position` bases?

Answer (score 28):

I've had the same problem, the Qt documentation is providing a pretty good answer: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#using-a-loader-within-a-view-delegate

The easiest solution is an inline `Component` with a `Loader` to set a `source` file:

```
ListView {
    id: contactsView
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.top: parent.top
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    orientation: Qt.Vertical
    spacing: 10
    model: contactsModel
    delegate: Component {
        Loader {
            source: switch(position) {
                case "Engineer": return "Employee.qml"
                case "Manager": return "Manager.qml"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any attempt to use `Loader.srcComponent` will result in missing any variable from the model (including `index`). The only way for the variables to be present is the children `Component` to be inside the main `Component`, but then only one can be present, so it is useless.

Answer (score 16):

I believe it would be better to implement one base delegate for all kind of `position` which loads concrete implementation depending on `position` or any other data properties using `Loader`

```
BaseDelegate {
    property var position

    Loader {
        sourceComponent: {
            switch(position) {
                case "Engineer": return engineerDelegate
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: engineerDelegate
        Rectangle {
             Text {  }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there the risk to incur in performance issues if the number of items is high? I know that `Loader`s are not blocking components, but he will have a lot of them working under the hood. Am I wrong?

Comment: It depends on complexity of delegates, but not on the Loader.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo yeah, I love them too, but I've never used them this way, so I was curious if there are performance issues with this solution. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack did you see the linked video? It should provide the answer to your question, sort of.

Comment: I'm on the beach, I will see it once on a WiFi, sorry... :-)

Comment: shouldn't  "sourceDelegate" be "sourcecomponent"?

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to do this now is using [DelegateChooser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-delegatechooser.html). This also allows you to edit the properties of the delegates, which is something that is more difficult to do with Loader!

Example inspired from the docs:

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.14
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

ListView {
    width: 640; height: 480

    ListModel {
        id: contactsModel
    ListElement {
        name: "Bill Smith"
        position: "Engineer"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "John Brown"
        position: "Engineer"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Sam Wise"
        position: "Manager"
    }
   }

    DelegateChooser {
        id: chooser
        role: "position"
        DelegateChoice { roleValue: "Manager"; Manager { ... } }
        DelegateChoice { roleValue: "Employee"; Employee { ... } }
    }

    model: contractsModel
    delegate: chooser
}
```

Comment: This should be the right answer now since a default Qt component

Comment: Best answer: no additional `.qml` files.

Answer (score 11):

I implemented it as follow:

```
ListView {
    id: iranCitiesList
    model: sampleModel
    delegate: Loader {
        height: childrenRect.height
        width: parent.width
        sourceComponent: {
            switch(itemType) {
            case "image" :
                return imageDel;
            case "video":
                return videoDel;
            }
        }
    }
    ImageDelegate { id: imageDel }
    VideoDelegate { id: videoDel }
}
```

**ImageDelegate.qml**

```
Component {
    Image { /*...*/ }
}
```

**VideoDelegate.qml**

```
Component {
    Item { /*....*/ }
}
```

Last note, check width and height of delegates. In my case, I had to set width and height of my delegate in `Loader` again.
Good luck - Mousavi

Comment: I did some research about performance. It seems that performance is very good and there is no need to any optimization.

Comment: What is the reason to write Component syntax once you declare the object in a different qml file? can't we just use source: in the loader?

Comment: Yeah you can. I used it because in this way it is more error-prone and possible to bind its properties easily.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible. `ListView.delegate` is a kind of pointer to a `Component` which will draw the items so you can change it.

For example:

```
Employee { id: delegateEmployee }
Manager { id: delegateManager}
...
ListView {  
    property string position   
    delegate: position == "Engineer" ? delegateEmployee : delegateManager
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, for you have to define the `position` before the list is populated, thus the delegate will be of a type and won't change depending on the content of the item.

Answer (score 0):

As far as you have only two types, the following code is as easy to maintain as easy to understand:

```
delegate: Item {
    Employee { visible = position === "Engineer" }
    Manager { visible = position === "Manager" }
}
```

In case the number of types will grow, it is not a suitable solution for it easily leads to an hell of if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because `position` is either `"Manager"` or `"Engineer"` and the delegates are saved in `Manager.qml` or `Engineer.qml` we can use a clever expression for `Loader.source`:

```
Loader {
   source: position + ".qml"
}
```

Here's the full source:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListModel {
        id: contactsModel
        ListElement { name: "Bill Smith"; position: "Engineer" }
        ListElement { name: "John Brown"; position: "Engineer" }
        ListElement { name: "Sam Wise"; position: "Manager" }
    }
    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: contactsModel
        delegate: Loader {
            width: ListView.view.width
            source: position + ".qml"
        }
    }
}

//Engineer.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Rectangle {
    property bool isCurrentItem: listView.currentIndex === index
    height: 50
    color: isCurrentItem ? "#0033cc" : "#585858"
    border.color: "gray"
    border.width: 1
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "white"
        text: name
    }
}

//Manager.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Rectangle {
    property bool isCurrentItem: listView.currentIndex === index
    height: 50
    color: isCurrentItem ? "#cc3300" : "#661100"
    border.color: "blue"
    border.width: 1
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "white"
        text: name
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAEknic1VJLS8QwEL73Vwz1KNQuiyKVRVA8KAq+0HM2HdvBNFPTWVeR/e8mta1bXwcv4hRK5vUl3zdDVc1O4EIuFqTvIxq5ySFbcWya6FwVCC8ReDulRs44R9P5wSjPQPtapaVpc0MmVB8ZrNAKvIBVFWYQH5AxcFWRlPEe1NyQEFsfP7IFWUQXw+pngBMuLRw4XtpfAlypCm6pwXH7mbKe59C9GvjeEC4/0DVdeAgqq0t2TXLnyWVQK+cvHJJVEOU7jfwZCyX+XaescnRrNwVbUi5lNrwjeQy/Njgqa3jhtMfo+cAmxMlDZeKhqme1iqKtrV6qUPJh7N9uwSVqUbYw/SrUjmt08gxzZgPUHC5cYH0sWL0LlOguanN8gtlsBhROLUCJVJSSwXbaupoNu2wMBPsQb6TpdKp1DH5GG9u74XtjNWfn9Uq6vrhw6nmU6KSbtLFrfJI1aft5aX8RumP7aWY96rIkwXcVxcNk7R6ty9mtzr9QU+vpNE3f1NzZmUz8+Ss152aBf6DmK8cdYbE=)