# Display QVariantList in QML ListView and use different Delegate depending on the type

Tags: qml

I want to expose a `QVariantList` from **C++** to **QML**. The `QVariantList` can contain data of types `Integer`, `QString` and `QStringList`. I want to use it as a **model** for a **QML** `ListView` and also I want to use a different `Delegate` for the elements **depending** on the **type** in the `QVariantList`. So data of type `Integer` are displayed differently than data of type `String` and `StringList`.

- How can I detect the type of the elements in the `QVariantList` in **QML**?
- How can I use a different `delegate` depending on the type?

I need a solution where I can change the exposed `QVariantList` and the ListView and its delegates will change.

Answer (score 0):

I have found no way of determining the type of a QVariant in QML, but I am using a different type now that exposes its type trough a string.

For the question of how to create a ListView with different delegates, the solution can be found here: [Different delegates for QML ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985972/different-delegates-for-qml-listview)