# In 'AppListView' are empty places where Loader should load Component with 'SimpleRow'

Tags: qt, qml, v-play

I have a code application written in QT/QML and V-PLAY on the github [here](https://github.com/pyroxar/VplayfirstApp):

My problem:

I want to use AppListView to display different elements (like Button or SwitchApp) in 'Ustawienia' (Settings) page dependent on elements in array:

```
property var typeOfElementsInSettings: ['switch','switch','button','switch']
```

I use 'delegete: Loader' to do It, I inspired in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985972/different-delegates-for-qml-listview). I load component from other file, one will have Button inside, other AppSwitcher. Loader inserts SimpleRow to AppListView, I know It because variable myIndex should increment when SimpleRow is added and It was incremented but I can't see anything. I mean that I see empty space in place where should be displayed SimpleRow.

See screenshot:

Android Theme:

[image: android theme]

iOS Theme:

[image: ios theme]

This is my code in Main.qml

```
NavigationItem{
            title: "Ustawienia"
            icon: IconType.cogs

            NavigationStack{
                Page{
                    title: "Ustawienia"
                    AppButton{
                        id: przy
                        text: "abba"
                    }

                    AppListView{
                        anchors.top: przy.bottom
                        model: ListModel{
                            ListElement{
                                type: "kategoria 1"; name: "opcja 1"
                            }
                            ListElement{
                                type: "kategoria 1"; name: "opcja 2"
                            }
                            ListElement{
                                type: "kategoria 2"; name: "opcja 3"
                            }
                            ListElement{
                                type: "Opcje programisty"; name: "Czyszczenie ustawień aplikacji"
                            }
                        }


                        section.property: "type";
                        section.delegate: SimpleSection {
                            title: section
                        }

                        delegate: Loader{
                            sourceComponent: {
                                switch(typeOfElementsInSettings[myIndex]){
                                    case "switch":
                                        console.log(typeOfElementsInSettings[myIndex])
                                        console.log("s")
                                        return imageDel;
                                    case "button":
                                        console.log(typeOfElementsInSettings[myIndex])
                                        console.log("b")
                                        return imageDel;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        SimpleRowSwitch { id: imageDel }
                        VideoDelegate { id: videoDel }
                    }

                }
            }
            onSelected: {
                //console.log("selected")
            }
            Component.onCompleted: {
                //console.log("Zrobiono")
            }
        }
```

This my code in SimpleRowSwitch.qml:

```
import VPlayApps 1.0
import QtQuick 2.9

Component{
    SimpleRow {
        x: 100
        y: 200
        text: name;
        AppSwitch{
            property int indexOfElementInSettings: 0
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.rightMargin: dp(10)
            Component.onCompleted: {
                indexOfElementInSettings=myIndex
                console.log(myIndex)
                if(switchsSettingsLogicArray[myIndex]===1){
                    checked=true
                } else {
                    checked=false
                }
                //myIndex++;
            }
            onToggled: {
                console.log(indexOfElementInSettings)
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            console.log(x)
            console.log(y)
            console.log(typeOfElementsInSettings[myIndex])
            console.log(myIndex)
            myIndex++
        }
        onSelected: {
            console.log("abba")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as a text, not as an image. Read how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I uploaded my code on the github.

Comment: You should create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which reproduces the problem. No one will download your entire project to look for errors. We're all busy people, but we're happy to help you if you make an effort.