# QML: Implement custom control with rectangles

Tags: qml, qt5, qqmlcomponent

[image]

I want to implement one control with 7 layers of rectangle. Top and bottom 2 rectangles are of the same size. But middle 3 rectangles are 1/3rd of width of the top and bottom 2 rectangles also two of such sets. The spacing between the rectangles will remain same.

How can it be achieved using the minimal code in QML. ( i.e. with 1 repeater or nested repeaters or some way thru models?)

I designed it using repetitive code by simply adding 10 rectangles and anchoring them properly but its not a good practice when things can be done with repeater / model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
Component{
    id:rec2
    Item{
        property bool flag: true
        width:300
        height:20
        Repeater{
            model:!flag?1:2
        Rectangle{
            anchors.left: (flag && index==1)?parent.left:undefined
            anchors.right: (flag && index==0)?parent.right:undefined
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 3
            height: parent.height
            width: (flag)?(parent.width/3):parent.width
        }
        }

    }
}

Column{
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    spacing: 10
    Repeater{
        id:repeter
        model: [false,false,true,true,true,false,false]
        Loader{
            sourceComponent: rec2
            onLoaded: item.flag=repeter.model[index]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible populate such rectangles with `GridLayout`. It works fine in [Qml Online App](https://www.qt.io/product/development-tools/qml-online-declarative-coding-app).

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

GridLayout {
    Repeater {
        model: [{row: 0, column: 0, columnSpan: 3},
                {row: 1, column: 0, columnSpan: 3},
                {row: 2, column: 0, columnSpan: 1},
                {row: 2, column: 2, columnSpan: 1},
                {row: 3, column: 0, columnSpan: 1},
                {row: 3, column: 2, columnSpan: 1},
                {row: 4, column: 0, columnSpan: 1},
                {row: 4, column: 2, columnSpan: 1},
                {row: 5, column: 0, columnSpan: 3},
                {row: 6, column: 0, columnSpan: 3}]
                
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.row: modelData.row
            Layout.column: modelData.column
            Layout.rowSpan: 1
            Layout.columnSpan: modelData.columnSpan
            Layout.preferredWidth: Layout.columnSpan
            Layout.preferredHeight: Layout.rowSpan
            
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ListView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html) for populating the given rectangles as delegates. You just need to handle the delegates in this case. Define two delegates as required and assign them to model of ListView based on their index as in given topic: [Different delegates for QML ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985972/different-delegates-for-qml-listview)