# Accessing delegates in QML from C++

Tags: qt, qml, qquickitem

I am trying to access the delegate component of the listview in C++ and want to alter it. Like in the code below, I am using QAbstractListModel to provide model to the listview and i have a delegate defined inside the listview which takes two String properties.

Now, at runtime i want to add another property to it from C++, based on the upper layer request. For eg: If i get a request to show 2 textfield along with an imageview in the delegate, in that case i have already two String properties but i dont have an imageview properties inside the delegate. Since, i do not know what exact request will come, i want to add the properties inside the delegate from C++. But i am not sure how to do it.

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.
Below are the code snippet.

**listviewComponent.qml**

```
ListView {
   required model

    delegate: Text {
        required property string type
        required property string size

        text: type + ", " + size
        }
}
```

**Model.h**

```
class Model
{
public:
    Model(const QString& type, const QString& size);

    QString type() const;
    QString size() const;

private:
    QString m_type;
    QString m_size;
};

class CustomModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum Roles {
        TypeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        SizeRole
    };

    CustomModel(QObject* parent = 0);

    void addElement(const Model& pElement);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
private:
    QList<Model> m_list;
};
```

**Model.cpp**

```
Model::Model(const QString& type, const QString& size)
    : m_type(type), m_size(size)
{
}

QString Model::type() const
{
    return m_type;
}

QString Model::size() const
{
    return m_size;
}

CustomModel::CustomModel(QObject* parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

void CustomModel::addElement(const Model &pElement)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_list << pElement;
    endInsertRows();
}

int CustomModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const {
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_list.count();
}

QVariant CustomModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_list.count())
        return QVariant();

    const Model& mod = m_list[index.row()];
    if (role == TypeRole)
        return mod.type();
    else if (role == SizeRole)
        return mod.size();
    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> CustomModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TypeRole] = "type";
    roles[SizeRole] = "size";
    return roles;
}
```

**Myclass.h**

```
class myclass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myclass();

    inline int createUI(QQmlApplicationEngine &engine){
        QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(engine.rootObjects().at(0));
        if (!window) {
            qFatal("Error: Your root item has to be a window.");
            return -1;
        }

        QQuickItem *root = window->contentItem();

        window->setWidth(600);
        window->setHeight(500);

        QQmlComponent listviewComp(&engine, QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/listviewComponent.qml")));
       
        CustomModel model = new CustomModel(window);
        model.addElement(Model("Wolf", "Medium"));
        model.addElement(Model("Polar bear", "Large"));
        model.addElement(Model("Quoll", "Small"));

        QQuickItem *listview = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(listviewComp.createWithInitialProperties({ {"model", QVariant::fromValue(&model)} }));
        QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(listview, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership);
        listview->setParentItem(root);
        listview->setParent(&engine);
        listview->setProperty("objectName", "lv");
        listview->setWidth(200);
        listview->setHeight(100);
        listview->setX(250);
        listview->setY(30);
 
       window->show();

        return 0;
}
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    engine.load(url);

    QQmlContext *item = engine.rootContext();
    myclass myClass;
    item->setContextProperty("_myClass", &myClass);

    myClass.createUI(engine);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: You should probably turn the problem around, add another property in the QAbstractListModel stating if a TextField is needed and then set that from C++ instead of trying to reach in QML, which can become ugly very fast

Comment: To do that also, i need to add a property in qml delegate which will map to a role in C++ model.

Comment: Yes, possibly of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985972/different-delegates-for-qml-listview